# Use pattern as Assumptions: How to properly extend working pattern?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, symbolic

I am struggling with an extension of using a working pattern used as `Assumptions` for `Simplify` and the like. Consider this:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[f[1][t]]]
Simplify[Conjugate[f[1][t]], Assumptions -> Element[f[__][t], Reals]]
(* Conjugate[f[1][t]] *)
(*f[1][t] *)
```

As intended, the pattern causes `f[1][t]` to be treated as real. However, there are also derivatives of `f[1][t]` appearing which are also real. Unfortunately, a similar idea as above does not work:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[D[f[1][t], {t, 2}]], Assumptions -> Element[D[f[__][t], {t, __}], Reals]]
(* Conjugate[f[1]''[t]] *)
```

Is it possible (if so, how) to use a pattern that also allows me to treat all derivatives of arbitrary order as real? Actually I would expect Mathematica to already do this, if it knows that the function that is derived is real...

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Your code returns `f[1]''[t]` on my machine (Mathematica 11 on OS).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/45431)

Comment: @yohbs Very interesting. I am running Mathematica 11.1.0.0 on 64bit Linux. Stitch's answer suggests that he was also able to reproduce the "problem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you need is different than what you enter. Your code actually evaluates the pattern:

```
Assumptions -> Element[D[f[__][t], {t, __}], Reals] // Trace
```

> `{{{HoldForm[D[f[__][t], {t, __}]], 
>     HoldForm[__!*Piecewise[{{__, __ == 0}}, 0]]}, 
>     HoldForm[Element[__!*Piecewise[{{__, __ == 0}}, 0], Reals]]}, 
>     HoldForm[Assumptions -> Element[__!*Piecewise[{{__, __ == 0}}, 0], Reals]], 
>     HoldForm[Assumptions -> Element[__!*Piecewise[{{__, __ == 0}}, 0], Reals]]}`

What you need is

```
Assumptions -> Element[Derivative[_][f[__]][t], Reals] // Trace
```

> `{HoldForm[Assumptions -> Element[Derivative[_][f[__]][t], Reals]], 
>   HoldForm[Assumptions -> Element[Derivative[_][f[__]][t], Reals]]}`

With this, you expression evaluates as expected:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[D[f[1][t], {t, 2}]], 
 Assumptions -> Element[Derivative[_][f[__]][t], Reals]]
```

> `f[1]′′[t]`

Comment: Ah right! Now I remember that I encountered a very similar issue a while ago, but didn't think of it anymore. Thank you very much for pointing this out!